# Magento 1.9 : How to get the total price of products added to cart based on product Attribute?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, product-attribute

I'm currently working on a Magento extension where I need help in getting the **total price of all products having the same attribute when they are added to the cart**.

Here is my code for a better explanation @ the shipping's carrier page:

```
foreach ($this->_quote->getAllItems() as $item) {


        $productid = $item->getProductId();

        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productid);


     $chilledFood = $product->getData('is_chilled_food'); // the custom attribute 'is_chilled' added to product backend, so if the product is chilled, the value will be 'yes' 
        if ($chilledFood) {  // need help from here?
            return $this->_price = ' ';
        }


    }
```

So I need help on knowing if the **customer selects chilled food in the cart. If yes, the shipping price will be an additional $5 from other types of food category. BUT there will be free shipping cost if the total chilled food amounts to $50 and above.**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help:

```
foreach ($this->_quote->getAllItems() as $item) {


    $productid = $item->getProductId();

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productid);


 $chilledFood = $product->getData('is_chilled_food'); // the custom attribute 'is_chilled' added to product backend, so if the product is chilled, the value will be 'yes' 
    if ($chilledFood == 1 ) {  // need help from here?
        $totalPrice += $product->getFinalPrice()*$item->getQty();
    }


}
echo $totalPrice;
```

Comment: I see, thanks for your help! After adding getFinalPrice(), the $totalPrice did increase when an item of the chilled food category is added to the cart (pdt A, pdt B, pdt C...). But the $totalPrice is not computed when the quantity per item (Eg. 2 x pdt A) is increased at Cart page. Any idea how to resolve this? Thanks Mohit

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: Please mark answer as correct if your issue solved. Thanks